# Bevelling equally in both direction

Tags: bevel

I have a box that is just a thin slice with different width and length.
I want to bevel the edges, but it is applying some kind of asymetry related to the aspect ratio of my box.

[image]

How can I make a bevel that is just a round corner with a constant curvature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just apply your scale before beveling with CTRL-A -> Scale

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had done it, but apparently not! Best and fastest answer :D